# Why does it has a constant val_loss:?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

[image]

I am working on somr dataset and am implementing a deep neural network. There are some typos that I am not familiar with. strong text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last layer's Neuron count to 2.

`model.add(keras.layers.Dense( 2, activation="softmax"))` 

**OR**

Change your last layer's activation to Sigmoid and keep *y_train* with single column

`model.add(keras.layers.Dense( 1, activation="sigmoid"))`

Answer (score 0):

Since your loss is `binary_crossentropy`, I presume that you are working with binary data. In that case, your output will be of 2 values. For such a case, using only 1 neuron in the last layer with `softmax` as the activation is not a good idea.

This is because `softmax` activation is meant for probability distributions. For example, if your classification is to predict if an image is a dog or a cat and if your dataset labels are one-hot encoded, then the probability distribution would look like this if the output is a cat:

`[1. 0.]`

If the output is a dog, it would look like this:
`[0. 1.]`

This just means that 1,0 is cat[True],dog[False].

And, 0,1 is cat[False],dog[True]

This depends on your labels and the order of the one-hot encoding.

In order to fix your issue, there are two methods:

````
1) One-hot encode your labels and change your last layer to 2 neurons with 
   ```activation='softmax'```


2) The other method is to keep the last layer with 1 neuron but to change activation 
   to  ```sigmoid```
````

**Code for the first method:**

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

y_train = to_categorical(y_train) # One-hot encoding your train labels
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)   # One-hot encoding your test labels

# Now run the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(11, input_shape=(num_of_features,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')
```

**Code for the second method:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(11, input_shape=(num_of_features,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
```

I hope this answer is of help to you. If you find this helpful, please upvote.